# Check for "-ms-expand" support

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

i'm trying to make a little script to style "select" tags in my html testing for the support of the "appearance" style property:

```
    if ("webkitAppearance" in select.style ||
        "MozAppearance" in select.style ||
        "oAppearance" in select.style ||
        "appearance" in select.style ||
        "-ms-expand" in select.style) {
      return;
    } 
    // else apply wrapper and style it.
```

The problem is that i don't know how to check for -ms-expand property, because it's not working and i don't want to user browser version sniffing in this case.

Comment: Well, look at how all the other ones are built. `-moz-appearance` becomes `MozAppearance`. You think maybe `-ms-expand` becomes `MsExpand`? That said, it might follow Chrome's pattern and be `msExpand`, but either way, just logic...

Comment: Already tried all msExpand, MsExpand, MSExpand...

Answer (score 1):

You can't check `-ms-expand` in javascript, because it is pseudo-element, and it do not affect to content. You can't detect it like `::before`/`::after` in `Modernizr`, but `-ms-expand` is enabled in IE 10+, so better will be to detect is IE 10 or higher by javascript:

Detection IE 11:

```
!window.ActiveXObject && "ActiveXObject" in window
```

Detection IE 10:

```
var isIE10 = false;
/*@cc_on
    if (/^10/.test(@_jscript_version)) {
        isIE10 = true;
    }
@*/
```

Comment: That's the "no other way found" solution for me.

Comment: Alhadis's solution is much cleaner and do not rely on hacks or browsers versions. This solution can break anytime a new version is released.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most optimal solution in terms of performance, but you could try this:

```
var expandSupport = (function(){
    try{
        var style = document.createElement("style");
        style.textContent = "#ie10-test::-ms-expand{ }";
        document.body.appendChild(style);
        var supported = !!style.sheet.rules.length;
        document.body.removeChild(style);
        return supported;
    } catch(e){ return false; }
}());

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(expandSupport ? "Your browser appears to support the -ms-expand pseudo-element" : "Your browser doesn't appear to support the -ms-expand pseudo-element"));
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xanmo33d/2/).

The reason this works is because browsers will discard any selectors they don't support or can't interpret, which means any browser that doesn't understand what the "::-ms-expand" pseudo-element is probably isn't IE10 or up.

Essentially, all that this code is doing is creating a dummy <style> tag, adding a ruleset that only IE10+ is expected to support, and reporting back the number of rules found in it.

Comment: This is a really "weird" solution, but surely original. Think i can test it.

Comment: Like Pinal said, support for pseudo-elements can't really be ascertained as easily as regular CSS properties, which means a less orthodox approach has to be taken to detect support. Of course, you can always try checking for support based purely on browser version (which is ALWAYS bad practice), but that's not a failsafe solution... there's no guarantee that future versions of IE won't use a different syntax for the pseudo-element, or drop support for it altogether. Not likely, but possible.

Comment: So, why Modernizr don't use that approach to test it? I'm going to profile this to see how it performs...

Comment: Well, "-ms-expand" is a vendor-specific extension and not on a standards track. It's not Modernizr's job to provide feature detection for non-standard/browser-or-platform-specific features like this one. It's also not a pseudo-element that's commonly used or referred to (hell, this is the first I'm hearing about it) so I can't imagine the demand for feature detection in Modernizr would be too great. :)

Comment: Tested, it crash on IE8, i will try to adjust the code to be ie8 safe.

Comment: Right, I wasn't aware that you were looking to support browsers as old as IE8 as well. In that case, the quickest thing to do is to just wrap the body of the function in a try/catch clause and return false in the catch block... I'll update the answer.